# Firefox add-on to hide a window on a selected day

Tags: firefox

I usually have a lot of unread tabs on one day, and have to leave them for the next day to read. The next day, I open a lot more tabs and have to leave them for another next day. This cycles everyday of the week. However, on Sunday I want to open a fresh new Firefox window to give me a break. On the next Monday I want to resume the old window from the last Saturday which having a lot of unread tabs. The next Sunday I want to resume only the window that I have left from the last Sunday.

Is there an add-on that helps me achieve this? I can use another browser like Chrome, but I miss the add-ons that only Firefox has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better than an add-on, I suggest you use Firefox's built-in "Profile" feature.
Use one profile for workdays, and one profile for weekend.

First, configure Firefox to reopen last session's tabs. Then close Firefox.

From now on you will need to start Firefox from command line like this (you can create a shortcut):

```
firefox -P
```

The profile manager will show up:

[image: Firefox profile manager]

The first time create the two profiles, the subsequent times just choose the profile you want.

Comment: I create a shortcut with the flag`-no-remote -P "profileName"` to open the profile I want directly, then schedule it to automatically open only on Sunday. Perfect. Thanks